# Possible to pass Printf.TextWriterFormat to MailBoxProcessor?

Tags: f#

I am building a parallel unit test runner using MailBoxProcessor.

I need to queue up print statements for a test, so I can print them once a test is finished.  I know how to send a string and build up a list so I can print them, but that forces me to use `sprintf` and pipe it into my print function and is not as clean as I would like.

```
[1..200]
|> List.iter (fun i ->
  sprintf "Test %i" i &&& fun ctx ->
    ctx.printfn <| sprintf "A guid %A" (ng())
    ctx.printfn <| sprintf "I am test %i" i
    ctx.printfn <| sprintf "A guid %A" (ng()))
```

You can see the full code here:
https://github.com/lefthandedgoat/prunner/blob/master/Program.fs#L36-L41

And see that `ctx` is an object with a `printfn` method that takes a string and posts it to a single mailbox that queues up messages until a tests is done, then loops over them and prints them.

My goal is to have the `ctx.printfn` look like this

```
[1..200]
|> List.iter (fun i ->
  sprintf "Test %i" i &&& fun ctx ->
    ctx.printfn "A guid %A" (ng())
    ctx.printfn "I am test %i" i
    ctx.printfn "A guid %A" (ng()))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but you may be able to achieve your goal via [kprintf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340484.aspx):

```
member x.printfn fmtStr = 
    Printf.kprintf (fun msg -> reporter.Post(Print(msg, x.TestId))) fmtStr
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about that! It'll come in handy in the future, thanks.

Comment: This works!  Thank you so much, I will go read about kprintf now!